# Is there a way to increase ttl in redis?

Tags: redis

I know there are several ways to set a specific ttl for a key, but is there a way to add some extra time for a key which has a counting down ttl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way to *extend* TTL. You need to get the current TTL, and then add some more TTL to it.

Wrap these two steps into a Lua script:

```
-- extend 300 seconds
eval 'local ttl = redis.call("TTL", "key") + 300; redis.call("EXPIRE", "key", ttl)' 0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Good question
2. there is no such command
3. I think it is a bad idea to have a command like that, you have to be careful when you use it.
4. Probably end up adding more time to the ttl than we expect. If you set it like 5 mins, the actual expire time will be close to 5 mins even if setting it multiple times in that request. But if you add multiple 5 mins to it, then we can`t be sure of the actual expire time